# XSL : Generated DOM seems in weird order

Tags: xslt

I'm experiencing an issue with an xsl cheatsheet. The generated DOM seems to be in wrong order. Here is my xsl :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="site-path" select="site-path" />
<xsl:param name="target" select="target" />
<xsl:param name="page-id" select="page-id" />
<xsl:variable name="portlet-id" select="portlet/portlet-id" />

<xsl:template match="portlet">
    <xsl:variable name="device_class">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string(display-on-small-device)='0'">hidden-xs</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="string(display-on-normal-device)='0'">hidden-sm</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="string(display-on-large-device)='0'">hidden-md</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="string(display-on-xlarge-device)='0'">hidden-lg</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <div class="portlet {$device_class}">
        <xsl:if test="not(string(display-portlet-title)='1')">
            <h3 id="article_{$portlet-id}" class="heading"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="portlet-name" /></h3>
        </xsl:if>
        <ul class="news-list gallery news-cards">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document-list-portlet/document" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
            <![CDATA[<div class="clearfix">&#160;</div>]]>
        </xsl:text>
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:if test="not(string(document-xml-content)='null')">
        <xsl:variable name="vignette-id" select="document-xml-content/article/article-vignette/file-resource/resource-document-id" />
        <xsl:variable name="attribute-id" select="document-xml-content/article/article-vignette/file-resource/resource-attribute-id" />
        <li class="news-list-card-item">
            <a href="{$site-path}?document_id={document-id}&#38;portlet_id={$portlet-id}" class="news-card">
                <div style="background-image: url(document?id={$vignette-id}&amp;id_attribute={$attribute-id}&amp;working_content=true)" class="news-card-image" />
                <div class="news-card-wrapper"> 
                    <div class="news-card-content">
                        <div class="news-card-category">
                            <span>Catégorie</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-card-title">
                            <xsl:value-of select="document-xml-content/article/document-title" /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <xsl:if test="(string(resource-is-votable)='1')">
                <br />
                <xsl:variable name="resource-score" select="resource-score" />
                <img src="images/local/skin/plugins/rating/stars_{$resource-score}.png" alt="Score" title="Score" />
            </xsl:if>   
            <xsl:if test="(string(is-download-stat)='1')">
                <br />
                #i18n{rating.resource_vote.labelDownloadCount} : <xsl:value-of select="resource-download-stat" />
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

After the render, the generated DOM is :

```
<li class="news-list-card-item">
       <a class="news-card" href="jsp/site/Portal.jsp?document_id=35&amp;portlet_id=100">
       </a>
       <div class="news-card-image" style="background-image: url(document?id=35&amp;id_attribute=64&amp;working_content=true)">
          <a class="news-card" href="jsp/site/Portal.jsp?document_id=35&amp;portlet_id=100">
             <div class="news-card-wrapper">
                <div class="news-card-content">
                   <div class="news-card-category">
                      <span>Catégorie</span>
                   </div>
                   <div class="news-card-title">Artu avec vignette 2</div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </a>
       </div>
    </li>
```

Here is the expected HTML :

```
<li class="news-list-card-item">
    <a href="#" class="news-card">
        <div class="news-card-wrapper">
            <div style="background-image: url(../../modules/news-card/image.jpg)" class="news-card-image"></div>
            <div class="news-card-content">
                <div class="news-card-category"><span>Mobilité</span>
                </div>
                <div class="news-card-title">Découvrez les neuf Autolib' customisées qui vont sillonner Paris</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Differences are :
In the expected, you got :

```
li > a > div >div > div ...
```

In the generated you got :

```
li > a
     div > a > div > div > div
```

HEre is a smaller reproductible example :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="portlet">
        <div class="portlet">
            <ul class="news-list gallery news-cards">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document-list-portlet/document" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document">
            <li class="news-list-card-item">
                <a class="news-card">
                    <div style="background-image: url(hello_world.png)" class="news-card-image" />
                    <div class="news-card-wrapper"> 
                        <div class="news-card-content">
                            <div class="news-card-category">
                                <span>Catégorie</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news-card-title">
                                Title
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is an example data used to generate my DOM :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portlet>
   <portlet-name>Actualités projet</portlet-name>
   <portlet-id>100</portlet-id>
   <page-id>1</page-id>
   <plugin-name>document</plugin-name>
   <display-portlet-title>0</display-portlet-title>
   <display-on-small-device>1</display-on-small-device>
   <display-on-normal-device>1</display-on-normal-device>
   <display-on-large-device>1</display-on-large-device>
   <display-on-xlarge-device>1</display-on-xlarge-device>
   <document-list-portlet>
      <document>
         <document-id>35</document-id>
         <document-date-publication>11/07/2017</document-date-publication>
         <document-xml-content>
            <article>
               <document-id>35</document-id>
               <document-title>Artu avec vignette 2</document-title>
               <document-summary>Artu avec vignette 2</document-summary>
               <document-date-begin>11/07/2017</document-date-begin>
               <document-date-end>
                  <document-categories>
                     <article-url>http://</article-url>
                     <article-attachment>
                        <article-vignette>
                           <file-resource>
                              <resource-document-id>35</resource-document-id>
                              <resource-attribute-id>64</resource-attribute-id>
                              <resource-content-type>image/jpeg</resource-content-type>
                           </file-resource>
                           <file-size>134783</file-size>
                        </article-vignette>
                        <article-body>&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Artu avec vignette 2&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</article-body>
                     </article-attachment>
                  </document-categories>
               </document-date-end>
            </article>
         </document-xml-content>
      </document>
   </document-list-portlet>
</portlet>
```

I'm using Google Chrome 59.
I'm searching the issue since 2 days and i'm currently lost. Can you help me?

Thx,

SLED

Comment: Are you going to make us find the difference? When asking other people to help you, make it easy for them to do so.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Post a **reproducible** example, including the input - preferably a smaller one: see [mcve].

Comment: If you are referring to the fact that the attributes within a single tag are rearranged, then no, you cannot control that.  The order of attributes makes no difference to the semantics, and the serializer is free to output them in any order.

Comment: Is that "DOM" the result of pure XSLT serialization or the tree you get when you feed the HTML created by the XSLT to an HTML parser? I am pretty sure at least in HTML 4 you were not allowed to put a block element like a `div` into a hyperlink `a href` element so browsers corrected such a structure I think. Not sure what happens nowadays with HTML5.

Comment: So HTML5 https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element allows anything but active content inside of an `a` element.

Comment: I just update with new data/code.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, my tags a rearranged. We cannot control that ? Is it a bug from xsl ?

Comment: You still have not explained which browser or "renderer" in general you use when you see the "wrong" DOM tree. As I said, HTML parsers can reorder the input to "fix" it. So simply try whether the browser or "renderer" does the same with static HTML, I have some doubts that the problem is related to XSLT.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 59. @MartinHonnen Yes you right. If I try with simple static HTML in my page frame, I still got the issue.

Comment: Try whether Chrome behaves different with static HTML if you add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of the HTML, if so, then, in your XSLT, add `<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>` as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`. If Chrome still does insist on reordering the elements and moving the `div` outside of the `a` element, then it seems its HTML parser does not (yet) implement the HTML5 allowed content model of `a` elements.

Comment: In fact, Chrome still insist to reorder tags. But what i'm not understand is on an other site than implement the style guide, tags are not reordered. It's the same techno, same browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my issue by adding a `&#160;` in my background-image div :

```
<div class="news-card-wrapper"> 
                    <div style="background-image: url(document?id={$vignette-id}&amp;id_attribute={$attribute-id}&amp;working_content=true)" class="news-card-image" >&#160;</div>
                    <div class="news-card-content">
                        <div class="news-card-category">
                            <span>Catégorie</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-card-title">
                            <xsl:value-of select="document-xml-content/article/document-title" /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks for all your answer and for @MartinHonnen explaination.

Comment: If the problem can be fixed by making sure that `div` is not empty then I think you should also be able to fix it on the XSLT side by using `<xsl:output method="html"/>` as that should make sure Chrome's HTML parser gets a `<div ...></div>` from XSLT and not `<div .../>`.